# RNGCryptoServiceProvider in Java

Tags: java, c#, random

I'm converting some C# code to Java. I can't find an equivalent to `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`. How do I do this?

```
private static String GetRandomSalt()
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] salt = new byte[32]; //256 bits
    random.GetBytes(salt);
    ...
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: Thanks. Please post the comment as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

Java's [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) is the equivalent you're looking for.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
random.nextBytes(salt);
```

The documentation details some other ways to get an instance of `SecureRandom`, depending on your requirements.